# stale element reference error after self.driver.back()?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting Selenium exception `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` after the first iteration of the `for loop`. My code is :

```
  for gc in grpCommune:
         self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", gc)
         self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")
         e=gc.find_element_by_xpath('//a[2]')
         e.click()
         sleep(1)
         ...
         genertaeCSV()
         self.driver.back()
```

how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stale Element exception occurs when the selenium reference bound to the element is no more valid, generally, this happens when you either navigate away from the page or refresh the page or the contents on the page is reloaded. In your case, you are trying to refer to the `gc` element which was captured with a reference before clicking the `e` element. The moment you clicked on `e` element using `e.click()` button, all the references in `grpCommune` is no longer valid. So, you will be able to run only the first iteration successfully with your code.

**How do I fix this code:**
Get the `gc` element within the for loop. Rather than using for each use for loop with the index.

Answer (score 0):

Stale element exception occuring when element in on page but selenium driver instance could not interect with that element.

Following actions can be resolve stale element exception

1.Refresh page by using  "**navigate(). refresh()**" method in selenium

2.using loop try to click or check visible of that element if that element visible or already clicked exit from loop.

Comment: Justin your first action never fixes the issue, as navigating or refresh does not assign the same reference id used by selenium.

Comment: Refreshthe  page only